# Преобразование кода на скриптовом языке в код на C++

Tags: c++

Есть ли какие-нибудь программы для конвертирования кода с какого-нибудь популярного скриптового языка в *C++*. Не интересуют конвертеры, которые добавляют зависимости в код. Для меня будет достаточно, если конвертер может преобразовывать лишь часть оригинального языка.

Пример того, что хочу получить:

```
a = [1, 3, 2]
a.sort()
print(a)
```

vvv

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

int main() {
  vector<int> a = {1, 3, 2};
  sort(a.begin(), a.end());
  for (int i = 0; i < a.size(); i++) {
    cout << a[i] << " ";
  }
}
```

Где может пригодиться:

1. Бывает необходимо написать небольшой скрипт, для которого критична скорость. Существование такого конвертера сэкономит время.
2. На скриптовом языке может быть проще написать алгоритм, да и будет он скорее всего нагляднее. Такой конвертер пригодится, чтобы не писать один и тот же код несколько раз.

Comment: Чем [Cython](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cython) не подходит?

Comment: @avp код на C++ пригодится для простой интеграции с существующим проектом. Если появится необходимость в еще большей производительности, я думаю, проще будем изменить уже сгенерированный код на C++.

Comment: https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/HipHop_(транслятор)

Comment: @pank: Cython и C++ поддерживает, [пример](https://gist.github.com/zed/1235546#file-build1darray-pyx). Наивно, написанный Питон, может быть быстрее наивно написанного C++, [пример](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9371238/4279). Существуют [множество инструментов](http://faster-cpython.readthedocs.io/implementations.html), которые принимают некое подмножество Python и заявляют оптимизацию какого-либо рода (e.g., theano, numexpr). Pypy `translate.py` умеет RPython (подмножество Python) в С преобразовывать, [пример](https://github.com/zed/loop-modulo-benchmark)

Comment: @pank,  не думаю, что такой проект (с ручной модификацией генерированного кода) вообще можно эффективно поддерживать. Вы вообще видели результаты декомпилятора? Подозреваю, что код сделанный генератором (после оптимизатора) будет не лучше.

Comment: @AlexanderZonov как получить c++ из php? Пробую так, но ничего не происходит: `hhvm -m translate a.php a.cpp`.

Comment: @avp оптимизация кода не требуется достаточно просто копирования того, что написано на одном языке в c++. Я уже пробовал написать простенький транслятор с Python подобного кода в c++ и что-то даже получилось. Думаю продолжить, но изобретать велосипед нет желания.

Comment: @pank, если "просто копировать" (т.е. по сути реализуются примитивные кодовые образцы), то может проще пойти по пути написания набора макросов?

Comment: @pank, @avp, а как транслировать в C++ из Python что-то типа `yield`? Да, hhvm не умеет транслировать в C++: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19026894/which-option-i-need-to-compile-php-code-with-hhvm

Comment: @AlexanderZonov, с `eval` дело еще хуже. Поэтому-то полную совместимость в впоросе не требую.

Comment: @AlexanderZonov, генерим код на основе [man swapcontext](https://linux.die.net/man/3/swapcontext) (или смотрим в сети реализации сопрограмм на siglongjmp)

Comment: @avp, а это точно совместимо с C++?

Comment: @pank, кстати, теоретически (если забыть об эффективности) `eval` тоже реализуем посредством компиляции в .so и загрузки во время выполнения программы.

Comment: @AlexanderZonov, swapcontext это системный вызов в \*nix (а уж из  какого языка получен машинный код совсем не важно)

Comment: @avp если писать макросы, то код станет менее читабельным. Читающему придется привыкать к макросам. Код на скриптовых языках обычно выглядит читабельнее и презентабельнее.

Comment: @pank, только для тех, кто не умеет писать на C/C++

Comment: @avp, уже транслированная программа должна уметь eval, то есть транслировать. То есть, транслятор должен быть на C++ - небольшое ограничение. Возникла еще мысль, что на .so можно сделать очень неплохую рефлективность - выбирай нужные символы хоть с помощью PCRE, но это только для C.

Comment: @AlexanderZonov, вот и вы (может того не замечая) подошли к важному выводу -- писать надо на Си.

Comment: Если Вы решили проблему - будет лучше вынести решение как ответ, а не оставлять его в теле вопроса.

Answer (score -1):

Найденые *transpiler'ы* в *C++*:

1. Typescript to C: [ts2c](https://github.com/andrei-markeev/ts2c)
2. [Статья в википедии](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Source-to-source_compiler), в которой есть список нескольких *transpiler'ов*.

Comment: Транслятор в С++ (из ссылки в вику) я  обнаружил только с [python](https://code.google.com/archive/p/shedskin/)

Comment: @avp если транслятор в Си адекватный, то его можно рассматривать как транслятор в C++, их там много, но из сриптовых языков мало.